# What's the meaning of "You should be telling people..."

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

I've come across the phrase below?

> You should be telling
>   people that’s what done it: home school.

I don't know if "should be telling" is a future continuous form or something else?

Could you please tell what the meaning of the phrase is?

The main text is:

> A MONTH BEFORE MY graduation, I visited Buck’s Peak. Dad had read the
>   articles about my scholarship, and what he said was, “You didn’t mention
>   home school. I’d think you’d be more grateful that your mother and I took
>   you out of them schools, seeing how it’s worked out. You should be telling
>   people that’s what done it: home school.”
>   I said nothing. Dad took it as an apology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You should do X

means:

> X is what you ought to do; doing X is the recommended course of action for you.

The reason your cited example uses the *continuous* form *(You should **be telling** them* rather than plain *You should **tell** them)* is to add "immediacy" (X is what you ought to be doing *right now*, as opposed to perhaps being something you might do at some time in the future).